# .htaccess rewrite rule not working on cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a website on my localhost,
Inside htdocs I have added a folder 'sitename' this contains all files including .htaccess. This is working fine on my local, but when I am uploading it on server the its not working.

.htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /sitename/

# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ /sitename/%1 [R,L,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /sitename/404

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitename/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

What should be the replacement for 'sitename' while uploading on cpanel
public_html??

Comment: "What should be the replacement for 'sitename'..." - Remove all instances of `/sitename` if the site is hosted in the document root and not the subdirectory. Aside: You should be creating separate VirtualHosts for each site you create on your development server, then you wouldn't need to make any changes when uploading to your live site.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your scripts in a sub-folder (example: `/public_html/sitename/` than below should work for you). However, if you keep your scripts directly in `/public_html/` (example: `/public_html/index.php`) than replace `RewriteBase /sitename/` with `RewriteBase /`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # let the PHP knows that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /sitename/      
</IfModule>

#prevent direct access to certain file types
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|psd|DS_Store|project)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 /sitename/404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sitename/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Let us know if you get any error message - it would help.

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: My folder structure is like this /public_html/index.php

Comment: In that case just replace /sitename/ with / ... I've tested it on my webserver and it worked.

Comment: How is this any different from the code in the question? Apart from the `.php` on the error document, the relevant bits look the same?!